# Typescript can't assign value to object key with hasOwnProperty type narrowing

Tags: javascript, typescript

I defined `hasOwnProperty` with type narrowing:

```
function hasOwnProperty<
  Obj extends Record<string, any>,
  Prop extends PropertyKey,
>(
  obj: Obj,
  prop: Prop,
): obj is Obj & Record<Prop, any> {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
}
```

I expected a straightforward function like this to work:

```
function addProp<T>(obj: Record<string, any>, key: string, val: any) {
  if (!hasOwnProperty(obj, key)) {
    obj[key] = val;
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting `Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcDyB3MAFAJzgAcBTAqATwB4AoRRTAIwCtFSAPKUsAE3UQAlUhDgFe1dFAIwwAcwA0iVGEoA+BfUSES7Lj37aiZCpQDSpSprUAKLXFYAuRq00Nix5zuKaAlM4c2GAFmNgAyIRExCW8lFXVEAG8tAlIoEAIkUJEoADoPOChCyjJctCxcb3IqXIhUABt6m0ClAuJfAG5aAF9aPtBIWARlXl5vagAVW0DnYVFxSWlZRWVVDUQAa0tnKRl5JQA3Bud43yStGGBEGwBCcpx8Y2rKZtdNy18z5IYGQIBtLaUAC6iAAvIgjvUugxer0gA)

This kind of makes sense because the type narrowing is saying that `key` doesn't exist in `obj`. However, this shouldn't prevent me from adding the key. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**
Also, it doesn't work outside of a function either:

```
const obj: Record<string, number> = {};
const key = 'key';
if (!hasOwnProperty(obj, key)) {
  obj[key] = 123;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to assert `obj is Obj & Record<Prop, any>` regardless of whether the test passes or fails?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to understand why TS doesn't let me add new keys to an object. `obj` is a `Record<string, any>` that doesn't currently have `key` as a property, which is fine. Then, TS shouldn't prevent me from adding `key` as a property.

Comment: @LeoJiang I made an update

Comment: @captain-yossarian That makes sense now, I misunderstood what Record<string, string> meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function hasOwnProperty<
  Obj extends Record<string, any>,
  Prop extends PropertyKey,
>(
  obj: Obj,
  prop: Prop,
): obj is Obj & Record<Prop, any> {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
}


function addProp<T>(obj: Record<string, any>, key: string, val: any) {
  if (!hasOwnProperty(obj, key)) {
    obj // <---------------- is infered to never
    obj[key] = val;
  }
}
```

In your case, `obj` after condition statement infered to `never`.
Why?

Because type of `key` is a string and `!hasOwnProperty(obj, key)` means that `obj` has no more `string` keys.

How to fix it ?

You can just add explicit generic for `key` argument.

```js
function addProp<T, Prop extends string>(obj: Record<string, any>, key: Prop, val: any) {
  if (!hasOwnProperty(obj, key)) {
    obj[key] = val;
    return obj
  }
  return obj
}


const x = addProp({}, 'a', 42) // Record<string, any> & Record<"a", any>
```

[Here](https://catchts.com/mutations), in my blog, you can find more issues with mutations in typescript

> @captain-yossarian's answer works for functions where I can have a generic for the key. However, in places where I can't use a generic, it still doesn't work (see edit)

This example just can't work:

```js
const obj: Record<string, number> = {};
const key = 'key';
if (!hasOwnProperty(obj, key)) {
  obj[key] = 123;
}
```

SInce you assume that `key` property is optional in `obj`, you should use `Partial`:

```js
const obj: Partial<Record<PropertyKey, number>> = {};
const key = 'key';
if (!hasOwnProperty(obj, key)) {
  const x = obj
  obj[key] = 123; // ok
}
```