# Defining a Typescript type for Object.entries that doesn't include undefined values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a type for `Object.entries` like this:

```
type _ObjectEntries<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T][];

function objectEntries<T extends Record<string, any>>(
  obj: T,
): _ObjectEntries<{
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K]
}> {
  return Object.entries(obj);
}
```

This works great when I know the exact shape of the object, e.g.:

```
const obj1: { a: number, b?: number } = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const entry1 = objectEntries(obj1)[0]; // ["a", number] | ["b", number]
```

Even though `b` is optional, this still works.

However, if I don't know the exact shape of the object (i.e. it has arbitrary keys), this adds `undefined` to the value:

```
const obj2: Partial<Record<string, number>> = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const entry2 = objectEntries(obj2)[0]; // [string, number | undefined]
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta&ssl=17&ssc=39&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA%20g8gIwFYQMbAKIDtgCcCWEAzgDwAqUEAHsBFgCZFQBKaA9rvSUXvlgOYAaKAEMsIAHwSoAXigBvAFBQoAbQDSUPlADWEEGwBmUMgF0AXGvXCyG06YDcigL6q9B42dWPFiwwFcsdHw2LCg2ZDRMHAJickoaOkYWdk5uXgFhMUkJAAplcORLMkFFAEpLeEj0bF44pRUNLTD3IxNTAFoAfmK7F2kGqFwIYH9cMMQUdAA6OjqiXIikMqdnX1RQnkKkAEZLeVFLLH8AWwQIXGEEHqhjs4uoZ1kFQ6gdq8sAJkenDawtua4EA7Z5LKK1WILJY7MqqAAMPkUfy2S0%20lgACiJcMB8CIADYkVgbNI8AiZW6nc64KTPA4iSzvKAIL4-JGbYCUGIgb5yME1GKEKHIT6whFOIA)

I'd like the type to be `[string, number]`.

I think the problem lies with `Partial<Record<string, number>>`. I expected this to mean "as long as the key exists, the value must be a number". However, TS seems to interpret this as "for any key, the value must be either a number or undefined".

I know there's a lot of issues around distinguishing between optional keys and `undefined`. However, specifically for `Object.entries`, is there a workaround that could work? I considered branding the objects to know whether they can have `undefined` values, but that seems too hacky.

Comment: Just remove `Partial` from `Partial<Record<string, number>>`.

Comment: But that would lead to issues similar to what you've addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68244197/599184. Throughout my app, I have objects (maps) with arbitrary keys, but non-undefined values. I'd expect objectEntries to not include `undefined`. For now, I made objectEntries accept an argument: `function objectEntries<KeepUndefined, T extends Record<string, any>>`

Comment: Is it important to explicitly type `const obj2: Partial<Record<string, number>> ` ? because without explicit type it works

Comment: Yeah because I have a lot of `const obj2 = {}`, then adding the props individually

Comment: TS does not play well with mutations. See here https://catchts.com/mutations

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `NonNullable<T>`, which excludes `undefined` and `null`, or possibly `Exclude<T, undefined>` if you only want to rule out `undefined`.

```
function objectEntries<T extends Record<string, any>>(
  obj: T,
): _ObjectEntries<{
  [K in keyof T]-?: NonNullable<T[K]>
}> {
  return Object.entries(obj);
}
```

Comment: No I don't want to filter out all `undefined`, e.g. `Partial<Record<string, number | undefined>>` would keep the `undefined`, but `Partial<Record<string, number>>` wouldn't.